# Validar que un registro no se duplique desde C#

Tags: c#

Buen día, solicito su apoyo ya que tengo un *reloj checador* en un *equipo local* con una `BD MySQL`, del cual quiero **insertar los registros de asistencias en una `BD` en `SQL-Server`**, ya genere ambas cadenas de conexión y estoy insertando los registros de forma correcta, estoy teniendo algunas complicaciones en la validación, para que no se dupliquen los registros, si ejecuto las diferentes consultas.

Adjunto los métodos que estoy usando para ver si pueden apoyarme a detectar donde estoy cometiendo el error.

Gracias por su ayuda a todos.

```
    //Metodo para buscar todos los registros en el reloj local

    public void BuscarChecadasReloj()
    {
        try
        {
            dtChecadasReloj = objRelojChecador.RegistrosPersonal();
            if (dtChecadasReloj.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drChecadasReloj in dtChecadasReloj.Rows)
                {
                    CNumeroEmpleado = Convert.ToInt32(drChecadasReloj[0]);
                    CNombreEmpleado = Convert.ToString(drChecadasReloj[1]);
                    CTipoChecada = Convert.ToString(drChecadasReloj[2]);
                    CHoraChecada = Convert.ToString(drChecadasReloj[3]);
                    CFechaChecada = Convert.ToString(drChecadasReloj[4]);
                    CEstatus = "PENDIENTE";
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dtChecadasReloj.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        BuscarChecadasIntelisis();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }

        //Método para buscar registros en SQL-Server
        public void BuscarChecadasIntelisis()
        {
            try
            {
                if (dtChecadasReloj.Rows.Count!=0)
                {
                    dtChecadasIntelisis = objCosmetica.ChecadasPersonal(CNumeroEmpleado, CNombreEmpleado, CTipoChecada, CHoraChecada, CFechaChecada, CEstatus);
                }                
                if (dtChecadasIntelisis.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drChecadasIntelisis in dtChecadasIntelisis.Rows)
                    {
                        INumeroEmpleado = Convert.ToInt32(drChecadasIntelisis[0]);
                        INombreEmpleado = Convert.ToString(drChecadasIntelisis[1]);
                        ITipoChecada = Convert.ToString(drChecadasIntelisis[2]);
                        IHoraChecada = Convert.ToString(drChecadasIntelisis[3]);
                        IFechaChecada = Convert.ToString(drChecadasIntelisis[4]);
                        IEstatus = Convert.ToString(drChecadasIntelisis[5]);
                        if (INumeroEmpleado != 0 && INombreEmpleado != "" && ITipoChecada != "" && IHoraChecada != "" && IFechaChecada != "" && IEstatus != "")
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i <= dtChecadasReloj.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (INumeroEmpleado == CNumeroEmpleado && INombreEmpleado == CNombreEmpleado && ITipoChecada == CTipoChecada && IHoraChecada == CHoraChecada && IFechaChecada == CFechaChecada && IEstatus == CEstatus)
                                {
                                    RegistradoIntelisis = true;
                                    ProcesarChecadas();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    GuardarRegistroIntelisis = true;
                                    ProcesarChecadas();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GuardarRegistroIntelisis = true;
                            ProcesarChecadas();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    GuardarRegistroIntelisis = true;
                    ProcesarChecadas();
                }
            }        
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }

    //Método para insertar registros del reloj en SQL-Server
    public void ProcesarChecadas()
    {
        try
        {
            if (RegistradoIntelisis)
            {
                objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Todos los registros se encuentran actualizados en la base de datos", true, lblAviso);
                BuscarChecadasIntelisis();
            }
            if (GuardarRegistroIntelisis)
            {
                objCosmetica.InsertarAsistencias(CNumeroEmpleado, CNombreEmpleado, CTipoChecada, CHoraChecada, CFechaChecada, CEstatus);
                RegistradoIntelisis = true;
                BuscarChecadasReloj();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: podrias especificar donde estas controlando los duplicados? y tambien la logica para saber cuando son duplicados?

Comment: En el primer método, busco todos los registros, en el segundo busco que esos registros no se dupliquen, y en el tercero si encuentro algún registro duplicado, lo regreso a la búsqueda.

Comment: Alberto yo por lo menos sigo sin tener muy claro como haces que eso funcion.. tienes variables globales?? pq comparas datarows contra datarows de si mismo? no compruebas antes de llenarlos que no exista? no compruebas contra la base de datos? me parece que tu problema esta mucho antes que esto. y tambien, cual es el error? entran registros duplicados? es logico que entren registros duplicados, pq este if (INumeroEmpleado == CNumeroEmpleado ... comprueba un reg contra otro, pero no sabe si ya comprobo los anteriores.. entonces da falsos negativos...

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada creo que la validación debe de ser en la base de datos coloca a tus columnas de fecha y hora que sean primarias y seria importante que mostraras tu esquema de **`BD`** para saber mas o menos que campos son los indicados.

es decir crea campos únicos en tu tabla donde registras la entrada
los campos que a mi consideración deben ser únicos son

```
NumeroEmpleado

TipoChecada

FechaChecada
```

con eso bastara para que no se duplique tu registro en un día.